# Toggle Airplane mode programmatically in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I wanted to toggle airplane mode programmatically without using entitlements for non jailbroken device using private framework. is this possible for non jailbroken device, if it is possible Can someone help me with sample code or ways to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the beauty of apple. For apple **Programmers** are not priority but **End users**

Comment: This should not have been closed as a duplicate. The method of implementing this, which worked prior to iOS 7, stopped working for iOS 7+.  Therefore, a new solution is needed.  This should not have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without using private API.so will be rejected by apple.
if still you you want to try [here](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/bring-airplane-mode-control-ba.html) is a tutorial for it.

1. What you can do is show a notification that guides the user to the Airplane setting and then the user changes the setting.
2. You can use Siri to open the Airplane settings screen